# real use cases of casting operators

Tags: c++

I want to know more about the casting (like static cast, dynamic cast, const cast and reinterpret cast) and when do we REALLY need that (real life scenario)? Any references/links/books will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article](http://www.acm.org/crossroads/xrds3-1/ovp3-1.html) will do.

Comment: Not such a great article. "... the result of the cast is undefined. Borland C++ 4.5, seemingly incorrectly, still performs the conversion, however." There's nothing incorrect about that. If an operation is undefined, anything can happen, including whatever the author of that article was surprised by.

Comment: There is no article (any more).

Answer (score 3):

Chapter 5 of [Scott Meyers' Effective C++ Third Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) has a discussion about casting in C++.

[image]

Comment: You know , the point of stackoverflow is to provide concrete answers, not pointing to "rtfm" or other outside directions ;-)

Comment: The question asked for links and books, so this answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this reference](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/typecasting/) to be to-the-point and easy to understand.